# TidSMPT inside ISAPI connection closes after a while

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy, delphi-xe7, isapi

What we see happening:

I have an ISAPI application that uses a TidMessage to send emails. It runs on our live web server and sends emails no problems for quite a while. Then all of a sudden it will stop working and we start seeing an error that says "connection closed gracefully". All I do is restart IIS, or reboot the server, and everything will start working again no problems.

What we are doing:

The ISAPI creates a TIdSMTP and TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL the first time it's needed. These instances are free these when the system gets unloaded. Either when ISS unloads the ISAPI, which it may not be doing or when we reboot, recycle, restart iis.

Then each time we need to send an email we create a TidMessage and any other needed objects. Then we free them when the email has been sent.

My theories:

I remember several years ago I dealt with a similar problem on an old NT box where the problem was the system was running out of pipes, then we would reboot and it would all work for another couple of months.

Questions:

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas as to what might cause this?
Can we be running out of pipes, or something similar?

Our SendEmail code:

```
    procedure TSendMailEngine.sendEmail(
  const recipient, cc, replyTo, subject: string;
  const plainTextList, attachmentList, htmlTextList: TStrings);

  procedure AddMailSection(parts: TIdMessageParts; const section, contentType: string; const parentPart: integer); overload;
  var
    msgPart: TIdText;
  begin
    msgPart := TIdText.Create(parts, nil);
    msgPart.Body.Text   := section;
    msgPart.ContentType := contentType;
    msgPart.ParentPart  := parentPart; // set to 0 if hasHtml and hasPlainText and hasAttachments, otherwise it defaults to -1
  end;

  procedure AddMailSection(eMailMessage: TIdMessage; const section, contentType: string); overload;
  begin
    eMailMessage.Body.Text   := section;
    eMailMessage.ContentType := contentType;
  end;

  procedure AddAttachments(parts: TIdMessageParts; attachments: TStrings);
  var
    cntr: Integer;
  begin
    for cntr := 0 to attachments.Count - 1 do
      if FileExists(attachments[cntr]) then
        TIdAttachmentFile.Create(parts, attachments[cntr]).FileName := ExtractFileName(attachments[cntr]);
  end;

var
  hasPlainText,
  hasHtml,
  hasAttachments: boolean;
  parentPart: Integer;
  eMailMessage: TIdMessage;
  //contentIndex: Integer;
begin
  parentPart := -1;
  eMailMessage := TIdMessage.Create;
  try
    InitMessage(eMailMessage); // adds date, encoding, from info, etc

    SetMessageHeader(eMailMessage, recipient, cc, replyTo, subject);

    hasPlainText   := Assigned(plainTextList ) and (plainTextList.Count  > 0);
    hasAttachments := Assigned(attachmentList) and (attachmentList.Count > 0);
    hasHtml        := Assigned(htmlTextList  ) and (htmlTextList.Count   > 0);


    if hasPlainText and not(hasHtml or hasAttachments) then
      AddMailSection(eMailMessage, plainTextList.Text, 'text/plain')  // only a text body
    else if hasHtml and not(hasPlainText or hasAttachments) then
      AddMailSection(eMailMessage, htmlTextList.Text, 'text/html')    // only an html body
    else // mixed message type
    begin
      eMailMessage.ContentType := 'multipart/alternative';

      if hasPlainText and hasAttachments and hasHtml then
      begin
        parentPart := 0;
        TIdText.Create(eMailMessage.MessageParts, nil).ContentType := 'multipart/alternative';
      end;

      if hasPlainText then
        AddMailSection(eMailMessage.MessageParts, plainTextList.Text, 'text/plain', parentPart);
      if hasHtml then
        AddMailSection(eMailMessage.MessageParts, htmlTextList.Text, 'text/html', parentPart);

      if hasAttachments then
      begin
        AddAttachments(eMailMessage.MessageParts, attachmentList);
        eMailMessage.Encoding := meMIME;
        eMailMessage.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';
      end;
    end;

    Send(eMailMessage);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(eMailMessage);
  end;
end;
```

**EDIT:**
The call to Send does a connect, authenticate, send and disconnect:

```
procedure TSendMailEngine.Send(eMailMessage: TIdMessage);
begin
  try
    if not fSMTP.Connected then
      fSMTP.Connect;

    if fSMTP.Connected then
    begin
      if fSMTP.Authenticate then
        fSMTP.Send(eMailMessage);

      fSMTP.Disconnect;
    end;
  except
    // there will be an exception if the sendFile is cancelled
    // we want to wait until it completes before emailing the config file
    on goodE: EIdConnClosedGracefully do
      fSMTP.Disconnect;//nothing
    //on another exception just let it rise up
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Are you leaving `TIdSMTP` connected to the SMTP server for long periods of time in between emails?  If so, then SMTP is not designed for that, and the server (or a firewall) is likely to disconnect you after being idle for awhile (typically up to 5 minutes, per RFC 5321 Section 
4.5.3.2.7). You would have to send other SMTP commands periodically to keep it alive. There are no heartbeat-like commands in SMTP.

Comment: Otherwise, if sending an email causes a "closed gracefully" error, simply reconnect and retry the email.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This code is being called intermittently and our load is not very heavy. Only a handful of emails a day. As per this, the last line before the finally "Send(eMailMessage);"  calls a function that internally calls connect, authenticate, send, and then disconnect. ...going to add that code to my question

Comment: Without seeing the actual TCP traffic, I can only assume that either 1) the server did not like something about the email data it was receiving and so it immediately closed the connection, or 2) some other exception occurred during sending to cause `TIdSMTP` to call `Disconnect()` internally (are you using SSL/TLS?) and then it raises the "closed gracefully" error on the next socket operation before you call `Connect()` again.